# How do you solve the equation $0.5^x = 2^x + 3$?

Tags: logarithms

I need help with the following problem: $0.5^x = 2^x + 3$
I know the answer is -1.72, but I have to explain step by step how to solve it and I'm not sure how. I know you're supposed  to take the log of each side, but I don't know what to do with the 3. How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the left-hand side to $\frac{1}{2^x}$, and then set $y=2^x$. This gives you a quadratic equation in $y$, which you can solve; finally $x=\log_2 y$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is $1/2^x=2^x+3$ which gives $2^{2x}+3.2^x-1=0$

Let $a=2^x$ then $a^2+3a-1=0$. Solve for $a$, take the positive root, and solve for $x$ by setting $x=\log_2(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

$0.5^x=2^x +3$

$(\frac{1}{2})^{x}=2^x + 3$

$\frac{1}{2^{x}}=2^x + 3 $ $/2^x$

$1= 2^2x + 3* 2^x$

Now you make substitution, in these exercises method that is often used.

**$y=2^x$**

Our eqation looks like this:

$1=y^2 +3y$

$y^2 +3y-1=0$

$y=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{9+4}}{2}$

$y=\frac{-3\pm \sqrt{13}}{2}$

$y_{1}=\frac{-3-\sqrt{13}}{2}$  or $ y_{2}=\frac{-3+ \sqrt{13}}{2}$

As we defined **y= 2<sup>x</sup>**, we know that it can not be negative number,so y<sub>1</sub> is incorrect, and we continue only with y<sub>2</sub>.

$y=2^x$

$2^x=\frac{-3+ \sqrt{13}}{2} /\log_{2}$

**(log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>x</sup>)=x)**

$x=\log_{2}\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$

put it in calculator and you get : 
**x= -1.723**

Comment: Welcome to Math Stackexchange! Did you know that you can type your math by surrounding it by `$` symbols?

Answer (score 0):

you should be knowing $0.5^x=\left(\frac 12\right)^{x}=\frac 1{2^x}$, hence

$$0.5^{x}=2^x+3$$
$$\frac 1{2^x}=2^x+3$$
$$(2^{x})^2+3\cdot 2^x-1=0$$
Now, solving the quadratic equation in terms of $2^x$ as follows 
$$2^x=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{(3)^2-4(1)(-1)}}{2(1)}=\frac{-3\pm\sqrt{13}}{2}$$
But $2^x>0\ \ \forall\ \  \ x\in \mathbb{R}$ hence $$2^x=\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}$$
$$\ln 2^x=\ln\left(\frac{-3+\sqrt{13}}{2}\right)$$
$$x\ln 2=\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}\right)$$

$$x=\color{red}{\frac{\ln\left(\frac{\sqrt{13}-3}{2}\right)}{\ln(2)}}$$